# "..........down 1,445 on the previous year." Why is it ""....on the previous year." but not ""....from the previous year."

Tags: prepositions

**The National Records of Scotland said 49,863 births were registered in 2019, down 1,445 on the previous year.** [BBC - Scotland population decrease](https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-scotland-53150553)

I understand that the number of births this year is less than that of previous year. So, there has been 1445 less births this year.

**"....on the previous year."** caught my attention. Why is it **"on"**? Aren't we supposed to use **"in"** for years?

Also, considering that the sentence is making a comparison between this year and the previous year, I would also be fine with **"....from the previous year."**

So, why is it **"....ON the previous year."** when it is making a comparison between this year and last year? Should it not be **"....from the previous year.?"**

Comment: "from the previous year" would ALSO be correct

Comment: Is this a British usage maybe? It sounds odd to me as an American. But to be clear, whether it's "on" or "from," both are shorthand for "when compared to."

Comment: I get the feeling the usage is financial/statistics 'industry-speak'… but it's a tough one to actually try search for. Beats my usually black-belt google-fu into submission ;)

Comment: With statistics and business, one often uses: year- **on-** year. Year-on-year, births are down by [number]  It's somewhat British. AmE would say over. It's used to compare things over two periods.

Comment: [Brits usually say "Up/Down **on** last year",](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=down+on+last%3Aeng_gb_2019%2Cdown+from+last%3Aeng_gb_2019%2Cdown+on+last%3Aeng_us_2019%2Cdown+from+last%3Aeng_us_2019&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) but Americans are strongly committed to ***from*** in such contexts, as that chart shows.

Answer (score 5):

When making comparisons between two years, in BrE, it is idiomatic to say either **… on the previous year** or **… from the previous year**. Both are fully understood. Of course it does depend on the exact context.
Whilst you would say **in such and such year** when talking about something like a day or a date, your example applies to comparing birth rates not dates, so **in** is not appropriate here. "down 1,445 **in** the previous year" does not make sense in this context as it is saying the birth rate was less in 2018  which contradicts the beginning of the statement talking about 2019.

Comment: on the previous year or over the previous year.

Comment: As a native AmE speaker, "on" sounds particularly strange to me. It's to the point where if I heard it, I would assume it's either a mistake or some dialect- or industry-specific usage.

Comment: @Hearth It's common in BrE. There are lots of similar small differences between BrE and AmE. I've edited my answer to reflect this.